# How many places one should apply for postdoctoral position

Tags: mathematics, postdocs

I need a suggestion in applying for postdoc position in mathjobs. In general how many places one should apply ? I mean, can my recommendation letter writers get disturbed if I apply for too many places and ask them to send email to too many places ?

Any help/suggestions will be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should apply all the places where you want to have a job, and no more.  That may sound flip, but there's no magic number; it all depends on how many jobs are the market and what sort job you would accept.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean, can my recommendation letter writers get disturbed if I apply for too many places and ask them to send email to too many places ?

Comment: @RIchardWilliams I used to ask for recommendation letters before applying. Then I realized it's enough to send cover letter/CV stating what I worked with whom. People who were interested asked for recommendation letters.

Comment: @Magicsowon This seems field-dependent. Many institutions won't even consider your application if it is incomplete, and will consider it incomplete if the requested number of recommendation letters has not arrived.

Comment: @RIchardWilliams If you're applying on mathjobs, your references only upload have to load their letter once and you can send it as many places as you want.  So that's not a concern.

Comment: @Magicsowon In math, that's a good way to torch your career.  People will read the letters if they are there, and if they are not, they will click to their next in a list of several hundred.